# Making a process started from a window the top most

Tags: c#, wpf

I have window which I show using the Show() method like

```
 _win.Show();
```

and this window's `TopMost` is `true`

With in the window on a button click a new process is started to open a file in the respective viewer

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"somepath";
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Start();

   void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }
```

I wan't this process to be the topmost till closed . What I tried is

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP =new IntPtr(0);
const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
```

and used it below `p.Start();` as

```
SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

This doesn't seems to work for me as `_wnd` is still the `TopMost`. However if I set

```
_wnd.TopMost = false;
```

After the process get started (let say notepad.exe) the notepad window gets behind the `_wnd` but on clicking the notepad window it will be brought to front. But in this case I  need to monitor if the process ended and then reset `TopMost`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try calling Activate() (or send WM_ACTIVATE) on the one you want at the actual top.  Topmost windows have a first come-first serve z-order.